# Node JS server not reflecting changes in server file

Tags: javascript, node.js

Iam new to Node JS when i make any changes to the node file it is not updating in the server and also when i change the port number and kill the server and start it again it is not working

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  res.end('Hello');
}).listen(8080);
```

Comment: *"when i make any changes to the node file it is not updating in the server"* What do you mean by that? If you mean you're expecting it to change immediately, it won't. The code is read into memory and executed from memory; if you change the code file, you have to stop Node.js and start ig again. *"when i change the port number and kill the server and start it again it is not working"* That will definitely work, I think you must have forgotten to stop it or something like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found a quick solution to fix this thing. You have to install a node module called as **nodemon**. This module helps to automatically restart your Server once you made the changes in Source code.

```
npm install -g nodemon
```

And nodemon will be installed globally to your system path.

You can also install nodemon as a development dependency:

```
npm install --save-dev nodemon
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, node does not automatically restart when there are any changes in the file.
You might want to try the package nodemon, which can watch for file changes and auto restart the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding an host name to your listen function

```
let http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
```